# What does "x" mean in piano fingering?

Tags: piano, notation, performance-practice

In many of Louis Moreau Gottshalk's scores, such as "Minuit á Séville", measures 16 - 18 (see below), the fingering is written "x" and not a digit. What does it mean?

I interpret "any", but I'm not sure.

[image: Gottshalk "Minuit á Séville", mm. 16-18]

Answer (score 15):

This is English Fingering.

Seldom used now, you find it in older editions of piano music.  The thumb is indicated by either a plus sign (+) or a cross (x) then the other fingers are numbered 1 (index finger) to 4 (pinky).

Comment: Here's the score: https://imslp.org/wiki/Special:ImagefromIndex/125518. YOu are correct, this is the "English fingering" notation.